# Ensembles 2 with NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate tableView update methods causing crash

Tags: ios, uitableview, ensembles

Using `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate method controller
`(_:didChange: at:for:newIndexPath:)`, between `tableView.beginUpdates()` in `controllerWillChangeContent(_:)` and `tableView.endUpdates()` in `controllerDidChangeContent(_:)`, results in objects with nil properties (including the uniqueIdentifier, which is normally set in `awakeFromInsert())` being created when merging changes from different devices, and related crash. The problem doesn't occur when only the `controllerDidChangeContent(_:)` delegate method with `tableView.reloadData()` is implemented instead.

Any advice on how to eliminate this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Adding tableView.reloadData() in controllerWillChangeContent(_:) just before beginUpdates() seems to solve the problem. It ensures that data in the tableView is in sync with that in the fetchedResultsController (FRC) before the tableView is modified by the FRC delegate methods.